# node server error - bindings.js crashing

Tags: node.js

I made this app 1-2 years ago, and I was new to node so I didn't make a proper package.json file when it was created. for some reason, it's not running any more. here is the error when i try to run [server.js](https://github.com/mrtunes/osc-network/blob/master/server.js).

```
elliott:nodejs_websocket_osc mrtunes$ node server.js
info  - socket.io started
/Users/mrtunes/Documents/webmusic/nodejs_websocket_osc/node_modules/node-osc/node_modules/osc-min/node_modules/binpack/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:83
    throw e
          ^
Error: Module did not self-register.
at Error (native)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at bindings (/Users/mrtunes/Documents/webmusic/nodejs_websocket_osc/node_modules/node-osc/node_modules/osc-min/node_modules/binpack/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mrtunes/Documents/webmusic/nodejs_websocket_osc/node_modules/node-osc/node_modules/osc-min/node_modules/binpack/index.js:1:99)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
```

it looks like the bindings module is from the osc-min folder. i tried to go in there and run an npm install but no luck. i put everything on [the github](https://github.com/mrtunes/osc-network)

Comment: If you run this on different version of node then before you can try `npm rebuild` command

Comment: i tried running the npm rebuild in a few of those folders to no avail. pretty much the same error regarding binpack and bindings comes up.

Comment: i found the source package that i was working off, and it throws this same error. https://github.com/peripecio/nodejs_websocket_osc